# Python Pandas replace replaces wrong

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
Date  WaterTemp
1       21.4
2       20.8
3       20.4
4       20.0
5       19.9
6       20.5
7       20.8
8       21.4
9       21.7
10       22.1
11       21.9
12       21.3
13       21.5
14       21.6
15       21.4
16       21.7
17       22.4
18       22.4
19       22.5
20       22.6
21       23.1
22       23.8
23       23.8
24       23.1
25       22.9
26       23.4
27       23.6
28       23.4
29       24.1
30       24.6
31       24.1
32       23.9
33       23.6
34       23.3
35       23.2
36       23.4
37       23.1
38       22.3
39       22.4
40       22.4
```

I want to replace the values of WaterTemp like this:

```
wt = df['WaterTemp']

for line in wt:
        if line <= 11.5:
            WaterTemp = WaterTemp.replace(line, "LWT")
        elif line >= 22.5:
            WaterTemp = WaterTemp.replace(line, "HWT")
        else:
            WaterTemp = WaterTemp.replace(line, "")
```

But the Result as .csv looks like this:

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
LWT,
LWT,
LWT,
LWT,HWT
LWT,HWT
,
,
,
,
,
,HWT
,HWT
,HWT
,HWT
,HWT
HWT,HWT
HWT,HWT
HWT,HWT
HWT,HWT
HWT,HWT
HWT,HWT
HWT,HWT
29,HWT
30,HWT
31,HWT
32,HWT
33,HWT
34,HWT
35,HWT
36,HWT
37,HWT
38,HWT
39,HWT
40,HWT
```

So it changes the Date values from 7 to 28.

I hope you can help me soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly tricky in that normally I'd suggest using several statements with `loc` but once you set a number of rows to `str` you introduce mixed dtypes and you can't compare `str` with `float`. Anyway you can achieve this using nested `np.where` statements:

```
In [61]:
df['WaterTemp'] = np.where(df['WaterTemp'] <= 11.5, 'LWT', np.where(df['WaterTemp'] >= 22.5, 'HWT', ''))
df

Out[61]:
    Date WaterTemp
0      1          
1      2          
2      3          
3      4          
4      5          
5      6          
6      7          
7      8          
8      9          
9     10          
10    11          
11    12          
12    13          
13    14          
14    15          
15    16          
16    17          
17    18          
18    19       HWT
19    20       HWT
20    21       HWT
21    22       HWT
22    23       HWT
23    24       HWT
24    25       HWT
25    26       HWT
26    27       HWT
27    28       HWT
28    29       HWT
29    30       HWT
30    31       HWT
31    32       HWT
32    33       HWT
33    34       HWT
34    35       HWT
35    36       HWT
36    37       HWT
37    38          
38    39          
39    40
```

Comment: Yes i had the problem with unorderable types str > float. But your answer worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: using `np.where` like my answer should work as I've shown

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `pd.cut`

```
df.WaterTemp = pd.cut(df.WaterTemp,
                      [0, 11.5, 22.5, 100],
                      labels=['LWT', '', 'HWT'])
```

---

```
    Date WaterTemp
0      1          
1      2          
2      3          
3      4          
4      5          
5      6          
6      7          
7      8          
8      9          
9     10          
10    11          
11    12          
12    13          
13    14          
14    15          
15    16          
16    17          
17    18          
18    19          
19    20       HWT
20    21       HWT
21    22       HWT
22    23       HWT
23    24       HWT
24    25       HWT
25    26       HWT
26    27       HWT
27    28       HWT
28    29       HWT
29    30       HWT
30    31       HWT
31    32       HWT
32    33       HWT
33    34       HWT
34    35       HWT
35    36       HWT
36    37       HWT
37    38          
38    39          
39    40
```

Comment: Yes would work too. Made it already with the other solution, but thank you too.

Comment: Actually, EdChum's is more correct.  I'm missing the match at `Date == 19`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new column with data points you can use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ReddyAl\Documents\water temp.txt", sep=' ')

df['WaterTempClassification'] = 'Normal'
df.loc[df['WaterTemp'] <=11.2, 'WaterTempClassification'] = 'LWT'
df.loc[df['WaterTemp'] >=22.5, 'WaterTempClassification'] = 'HWT'
```

Output:

```
   Date WaterTemp   WaterTempClassification
0   1   21.4    Normal
1   2   20.8    Normal
2   3   20.4    Normal
3   4   20.0    Normal
4   5   19.9    Normal
5   6   20.5    Normal
6   7   20.8    Normal
7   8   21.4    Normal
8   9   21.7    Normal
9   10  22.1    Normal
10  11  21.9    Normal
11  12  21.3    Normal
12  13  21.5    Normal
13  14  21.6    Normal
14  15  21.4    Normal
15  16  21.7    Normal
16  17  22.4    Normal
17  18  22.4    Normal
18  19  22.5    HWT
19  20  22.6    HWT
20  21  23.1    HWT
21  22  23.8    HWT
22  23  23.8    HWT
23  24  23.1    HWT
24  25  22.9    HWT
25  26  23.4    HWT
26  27  23.6    HWT
27  28  23.4    HWT
28  29  24.1    HWT
29  30  24.6    HWT
30  31  24.1    HWT
31  32  23.9    HWT
32  33  23.6    HWT
33  34  23.3    HWT
34  35  23.2    HWT
35  36  23.4    HWT
36  37  23.1    HWT
37  38  22.3    Normal
38  39  22.4    Normal
39  40  22.4    Normal
```

Comment: OP didn't ask for a new column, they wanted to overwrite an existing column